# I want to join two meshes but it won't rig?

Tags: mesh, rigging, 3d-view, armature

[image]I need help with this rig. The face is a material and I want that on top of the head. But I know it doesn't rig when there are double faces on there. What to do?

Comment: once you've joined the face, select its vertices in Edit mode and in the Vertex Groups list, select the group it is supposed to be part of and click Assign

Comment: If you need just control Face object by bone, you don't have to join them. Just select the Face object and Armature object with Shift and Ctrl+P > Bone.

Comment: Omg the last thing worked!!!! Thank you @vklidu